# In jQuery what does !clickover.hasClass('navbar-toggler') mean?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I created a nav menu that I will be using in a Bootstrap 4 based site. I found some jquery code that I modified to suit the functionality that I want but there's one line of code I don't quite understand. If anyone can help break it down for me that that would be amazing. I've been playing around with it in the developer tools to try to further understand it. I can walk you through the logic I understand and hopefully, you can steer me in the right direction.

With the code below, it is looking for an event to bubble up. Then it's taking the nav with a class of .navbar-collapse and checking to see if it has the class of show. It is in this stage that I'm lost. I know the bang tag (!) is used for a switch and to mean the opposite of whatever the assigned value is, so my brain interprets it as no event and if there is a class of .navbar-toggler then to hide the element? That doesn't make sense since a click would be needed in order to hide the element in the first place. What exactly is happening here?

```html
   

 nav class="navbar sticky-top">
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample">MENU</button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseExample">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
           <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">HOME</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="dropdown_target" href="#">PROJECTS
             <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_target">
             <div>
              <a class="dropdown-item">WEB</a>
             </div>

             <div>
              <a class="dropdown-item">GRAPHICS</a>
             </div>
            </div>

           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">HIRE</a>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        </nav>
```

```js
$(document).click(function(event) {
                var clickover = $(event.target);
                var $navbar = $(".navbar-collapse");
                var _opened = $navbar.hasClass("show");
                var $main = $('main');
                if (_opened === true  && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggler")) {
                    $navbar.collapse('hide');
                    $main.removeClass('menu-active');

                } else {
                    $main.addClass('menu-active');
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely correct, `!` does invert the meaning of the boolean value it's attached to. So `!true` === `false`, and `!false` === `true`.
In this case, it's checking to see if the navbar is open (`_opened === true...`), and if the the 'clickover' element DOES NOT HAVE the class of `navbar-toggler`, then the menu will be collapse toggled (see [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#collapsehide)). This means it'll close the navbar when the navbar-toggler isn't clicked and it's open.